# Length of GroupedData "object of type 'GroupedData' has no len()"

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with computing the length of a grouped data:

> object of type 'GroupedData' has no len()

I have the following code in PySpark:

```
gb = df.groupBy('A_1')
l = len(gb)
print(l)
```

But I get this error. How can I compute the length of `gb`?

This code can be run with pandas:

```
gb = df.groupby(['A_1'])
l = len(gb)
print(l)
```

But in PySpark, I face problem.

Comment: Spark is not Pandas. You cannot use the same methods. You can access spark doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html). If you want to use spark as pandas, you can use [koalas](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is the use of `len`. You cannot use it with Spark.
I think, you want to use `count`.

```py
df = spark.range(10)
print(df.count())
# 10
```

`groupBy` is a "partial" step. You cannot do a groupBy without an aggregation after.
If you simply want to count the number of different "A_1", do :

```py
df.select("A_1").distinct().count()
```